# How to re-oder serial numbers after remove deleted row from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

[image]After i deleted row the serial number column number are not re-ordered

I have Delete button in each row on click calling Ajax to delete record from data. It's deleting record from data base, after deleted recording I want to display remain data and remove particular row in table but it's changing pagination and refreshing the whole table.

```
var owner_table = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    owner_table = $('#owners_table').DataTable();

});

function deletehouseowner(oid, rid) {

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "HTML",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "oid": oid
        },
        url: "houseowner_delete.php",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg === "failure") {

            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                var table = 'owners_table';
                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                var id = row.attr("id");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var siblings = row.siblings();
                    owner_table.row($('#row_' + rid)).remove().draw();
                    siblings.each(function (index) {
                        $(this).children().first().text(index + 1);
                    });
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

API method [`draw()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) accepts optional parameter that controls how the table should be updated.

Pass `false` to [`draw()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) function to preserve current page, see the code below:

```
owner_table.row($('#row_'+rid)).remove().draw(false);
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bhq0y5m/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: owner_table.row($('#row_'+rid)).remove().draw(false);This also same issue as it is previous.

Comment: @venkatasudhakarpalisetty, added example to demonstrate that my solution works. There could be other issues with your code, for example, not sure if `this` refers to the button being clicked.

Comment: ok that working fine.but after delete a row the serial numbers are not re-order please give solution to this

Comment: I  wrote table code like this: <?php
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT oid,fname,lname,address,email,zipcode,phone,creditcard_name,creditcard_number,expiration_month,expiration_year,profileimg,status FROM houseowner where activation IS NULL ORDER BY oid DESC");  <td class="width10 text-center">Sl. No.</td><td class="text-center">$i=1;
             while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
              
             {<?php echo $i; ?></td>}